# I created an instance group and all of the 100 created instances have this red exclamination mark saying this instance doesn't exist

Tags: google-compute-engine, multiple-instances, gce-instance-group

I created an instance group and all of the 100 created instances have this red exclamation mark saying this instance doesn’t exist saying it is either terminated or never created what can I do? I tried creating another one but still the same or it created only one.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the instance and its zone you can use https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/compute.zoneoperations.list/m/compute/v1/compute.zoneOperations.list to find an operation used for creating that instance and see if it contains any errors. To list operations connected to your instance you should enter in filter field: targetLink eq '.*your-instance-name'.